# Bug in Inkfilepicker Android library

Tags: android, filepicker.io

I'm using your Android library for an implementation of InkFilePicker in an Android app, but I'm having some issues: trying to upload a file, I get an "org.json.JSONException", since there's no value for "key" in the JSON I obtain as a response. I can handle the exception, but this would mean touching the library's files: is it ok? It shouldn't, I think. Library is outdated, or bugged: is there someone who already encountered this problem?

Another little problem: how can I change the default name "testfile.file" to the original one (e.g. "foo.jpeg")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I configured my S3 settings and everything went ok after that.